# Create multiple .apk

Tags: android

I am working on one android project. I need to launch multiple .apk for various locations. I would require an ant or build script so that i can pass the latitude and longitude of particular location or .csv of all the location and it will generate multiple .apk's for one project. is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Locally create multiple APKs**

Imho the best way is to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) with different [Maven-Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). Then you might do something like:

```
mvn -Plocation1 package
mvn -Plocation2 package
```

both will result in an `APK` with different properties if you configure it to do so.

Look at http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/ there you find the android plugin to use with Maven. An example [POM](http://fernandoribeiro.eti.br/2010/02/17/sample-pom-for-maven-android-plugin-2-2-2/) to use.

Sure you might also do this with ANT but at least from my experience if you do serious development Maven costs less time and supports code-quality(as long as the developer is interested in quality).

There are also examples for maven to make android instrumentation tests.

**Android market**

If you look for an android market solution you might look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/index.html).